# Deploy react app on Heroku: 'X-Frame-Options error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I write my react app using `create-react-app` then I deploy it on Heroku. In my app, I display an iframe that loading another web page. I can run that on local, but when deploying to heroku I meet this error:

> Refused to display 'some_url' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

How can I config to fix this problem when deploy to heroku.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If webserver sent in headers `X-Frame-Options` to `deny` that means you can't embed this URL. More on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

It is interesting though that you could display it locally. Are you sure it was the same URL? Maybe you used proxy locally and proxies often remove headers.

Comment: I think maybe heroku block this.